# Is it possible for the typical value of a variable to not be in a data set?

Tags: mean, sample

Let's suppose I have a quantitative variable which stores the height of 300 different roller coasters. Assume that the 300 roller coasters provide a good representation of the total population of roller coasters.

Furthermore, all of the roller coaster heights are even numbers (I know that this is extremely improbable, but scenario is for the purposes of the question). The distribution for the heights of the 300 different roller coasters is roughly symmetric, being centered around 135 feet tall. There are no outliers in the data.

If I were to find a value for the typical height of a roller coaster, since there are no outliers, I would logically use the average. Suppose this is 135 feet.

*Would 135 feet, then, be the typical value for the height of a roller coaster, even if 135 is not a data point in the sample of roller coasters? Is the typical value for a data point in the population restricted to the values of the data points in the sample?*

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sample mean of a distribution does not have to be a data point in the sample. For another example suppose you have the sample values 1, 2, 3, 4 then the sample mean is 2.5.  There is a plethora of such examples.

Comment: @MichaelChernick So the typical value of a data point in a population can be outside the data points of the sample? Doesn't this seem slightly counterintuitive?

Comment: @KaienYang Define *typical value*. What does that mean?

Comment: I am talking about the sample mean if that is what you mean by typical value.  There is nothing coumterintuitive about that.  Calling this a typical value of a data point doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @KaienYang You have defined the roller coaster heights to be discrete (and even) values. If by *typical value* you imply the sample mean, then the sample mean won't necessarily be in the sample. Consider a sample of size 4: $H=\{148,152,152,154\}$. The sample mean is simply $\bar{H}=151.5$, which you'll see isn't in the sample. However, if you define *typical value* as the mode, then this **is** in the sample as the mode is equal to 152.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely, if you define "typical value" to encompass things where they often aren't sample values, like the mean.

The mistake here is using "typical value" in two different ways, at first in a very loose and undefined way (indeed, you were choosing what it means after you saw the data), and then later in a more specific, incompatible way (concern that a typical value should actually occur if it's really "typical").

This is essentially a weak form of the fallacy of [equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation).

I'd suggest that you avoid the term "typical value" altogether, since it's open to exactly this sort of confusion (even if you don't confuse yourself, you'll be likely to mislead someone else).

I realize this use of the term "typical value" isn't something you made up. I expect you probably got it right out of an elementary stats text (or class notes) that tries too hard to avoid saying anything precise for fear of making it look like mathematics, and so uses a lot of loose terminology open to this kind of shift in meaning, which is just what leads to this misunderstanding. Some other books use "central value" which is perhaps a little more neutral, but still has a tendency to imply particular properties that may not be true of some location-measures. The mode, for example, is frequently far from the center.

Choose the mean as a measure of location if you like (though that's perhaps not the best way to arrive at a choice) but don't then expect means to have properties not possessed by means.

If you really want a measure that will be present in the data don't choose the mean, choose one that emphasizes "typicality" in the second sense you used it -- most obviously that suggests a mode. It's best not to get too hung up on what the loose term means, it's not a real thing, it's just an attempt to gather several quite different location-like notions under a single umbrella term.